# Sending and receiving data between phonegap app and database on x10 hosting

Tags: android, sql, cordova, web-hosting

I am trying to create a login system on a phonegap app that references data that is stored in a database that is hosted on x10hosting. Basically the app will log in after it has accessed the database to make sure the user login and password are correct. How would this be implemented and would this be the best way to do this?

Comment: You will need to create an API to bridge between the app and the database on the server.

Comment: ok thanks, could you point me in the direction of any tutorials relating to this?